# How can you tell if SendMessage() was successful (message was delivered)?

Tags: winapi

is it possible to determine if a SendMessage() call was successful and delivered my message to the target window?

The SendMessage() description in the Windows API seems quiet on this and only says the following:

> The return value specifies the result of the message processing; it depends on the message sent.

This obviously refers to the fact that the return code reflects the value returned by the wndproc of the target window.

But what will the return code be if the message wasn't delivered at all (e.g. due to access control, or due to the window having been destoroyed in the meantime)? How can I detect such situations?

Comment: depends on the message. could you have a response sent back?

Comment: It's a WM_USER message to my own code, so I have full control here. A simple response (like wndproc returning TRUE) will not do, because it appears the return value of SendMessage() is undefined if the delivery failed. So it seems it is no guaranteed that SendMessage() will not return TRUE in such a situation.

Comment: i mean have the other application `SendMessage` back.

Comment: This is of course possible, I was just wondering if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: if you are writing both sides, IPC might be a better choice too

Comment: I am sending  data to the GUI thread (with the intention for my data to be displayed immediately), so I thought SendMessage() was the natural choice, since it delivers to the GUI thread.

Comment: *How can I detect such situations?* - by call `SetLastError(0)` before call `SendMessageW` and `GetLastError()` after call. if `GetLastError() == 0` - message was delivered, if no - fail

Comment: `SendMessage` has a single return value, that cannot be used to reliably distinguish between success and failure. [SendMessageTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagetimeoutw), on the other hand, returns both a success/error indicator as well as the result of the message processing.

Comment: With `SendMessageTimeout`, I don't see a way of knowing whether the message was received by the target window. Because the timeout can happen both before the wndproc got called, and while the wndproc is processing the message.

Comment: [`SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagetimeoutw): *"The function does not enforce the time-out period as long as the receiving thread is processing messages."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if [`SendMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) fail, it set last win32 error code, which we can get back via call [`GetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d852e148-985c-416f-a5a7-27b6914b45d4). and returned error code, in case fail, never will be 0 (`NOERROR`) despite this is clear not documented. but how detect that `SendMessage` is fail ? here we can not base on return value. but we can [`SetLastError(NOERROR)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms680627) before call `SendMessage` and check `GetLastError()` after:

- if `SendMessage` fail - value returned by `GetLastError()` will be
  not 0. (most common in this case `ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE` or
  `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`).
- if we still got 0 as last error - this mean that message was
  delivered with no error.
- however, possible case, when during `SendMessage` call, some window procedure 
  in current thread will be called and
  code inside window procedure, set last error to non 0 value. so we
  get finally not 0 last error, but not because `SendMessage` fail.
  distinguish between these two cases very problematic

-

```
    SetLastError(NOERROR);
    LRESULT lr = SendMessageW(hwnd, *, *, *);
    ULONG dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
    if (dwErrorCode == NOERROR)
    {
        DbgPrint("message was delivered (%p)\n", lr);
    }
    else
    {
        DbgPrint("fail with %u error\n", dwErrorCode);
    }
```

Comment: If this is a cross-thread call, of course it will work well because there are no intervening API calls which could call `SetLastError()`.  But if sending to a window owned by the current thread, couldn't the window procedure do something that changes the last error code, and that couldn't be distinguished between a last-error code set by `SendMessage()` itself?

Comment: @BenVoigt - yes, you right, if we sending message to a window owned by the current thread - window procedure will be called on current thread, and possible change error code to not 0. I not think about this case at begin. really this is break my "solution". need think more. only possible that question primary for remote windows - for current thread window this is usually not actual problem

Comment: @ben: This doesn't work reliably even in the case where `SendMessage` is a cross-thread call, as `SendMessage` will dispatch incoming cross-thread messages (see [When can a thread receive window messages?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040608-00/?p=38983)).

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, you are right. unfortunately cannot delete now self answer (because it accepted)

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to reliably tell, whether a call to `SendMessage` succeeded or failed. After all, it only has a single return value, and the entire range of values is used. There is no designated error value.

Playing tricks with the calling thread's last error code won't work either. The scheme proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55787920/1889329) (clearing the last error code prior to the call and evaluating it after the call) is brittle. It's easy to see that it can fail, when sending a message to a window owned by the calling thread (as that window's window procedure is at liberty to change the last error any way it sees fit).

It's not quite as well known, that this can also fail when sending a message to a window owned by a different thread. The code suggests, that no intervening API call can happen in the calling thread. Yet in that scenario, `SendMessage` will also dispatch incoming cross-thread messages (see [When can a thread receive window messages?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040608-00/?p=38983)), allowing the thread's last error code to change.

The only option then is to use [`SendMessageTimeoutW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagetimeoutw), as that API reports both the result of the call, as well as an error/success indicator. Passing the `SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG` flag makes sure that an arbitrarily chosen timeout will not adversely affect the outcome.